# how can i open my .sgrd file?

Tags: c, linux, qt

I need to open my system monitor in the **QTCreator**, but when I try to do it I obtain the following error message:

```
/home/arakul/sysmon.sgrd: 2: /home/arakul/sysmon.sgrd: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

I am trying to open the system monitor by using the following command:

```
 execlp("/home/arakul/sysmon.sgrd","",NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my stupid question. I must use command ksysguard with parametrs.

```
 system("ksysguard --desktopfile sysmon.sgrd");
```